# Ubuntu in enterprise

Tags: vmware, rdp, vdi

We currently have Windows XP desktop (around 50 computers) in an VDI environment (View Hoziron aka View)

We think to upgrade our installation and have choice :
- Upgrade to Windows 7 (or 8)
- Jump in Linux World

Upgrade to Windows means : Licence + VDA subscription = Lot of money put in trash every year
So, we are thinking to jump in Linux world

Most of our employees have ThinClient that support PCoIP protocol (and RDP) (few of them have simple PC with Windows XP) and are connected to a Windows XP virtual machine
VMware Horizon connect to the local session. IT guys use LogMeIn installed on all VMs to help employee when they have trouble.

I have try xrdp on Ubuntu, but Unity desktop doesn't work with xrdp, so I have installed Xunbutu

xrdp create a new X session, but :

- If any software need 'root' password, the window popup in the local X session, not the RDP session (can run application from terminal with 'sudo', but we need to known that application ask for 'root' password)
- IT guys are unable to connect to this RDP session to help employees if have any trouble (I have try to start TeamViewer from an RDP session, it's doesn't work)

Thanks for your help

Comment: For older Adobe version : ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix
(anwser found on askubuntu.com)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: You do not need logmein or teamviewer if you need to connect to those 50 Ubuntu desktops. RDP is all you need. Also: 50 desktops it might be worth to also use puppetmaster and a local repository (that way you can install software from your own machine to one or all of the desktops). "Or can we use RDP to connect directly to the console instead on creating virtual console" = desktop. But you also can use SSH for console of course.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I probably used the wrong words.
Each employee have a ThinClient supporting PCoIP and RDP protocol. 
When connected on Ubuntu with the help of xrdp,
it's not connected to the desktop that you see on the screen of the physical computer where Ubuntu is installed (CTRL+ALT+F8).
I need to be able to remote control that session (without disconnecting employee) in case of employee have trouble
With TeamViewer, I can take control of the main X session (CTRL+ALT+F8) only, not RDP session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open software center from a terminal by first opening a terminal and then typing the following command:

```
sudo software-center
```

The password prompt will be prompted from within the terminal instead of the desktop. You must use the password of the user that is logged into the desktop. This user must have sudo or admin privileges.

Also, I've never used "Landscape Service" but it sounds like that may be along the lines of something you are looking for as a management tool. - [landscape.canonical.com](https://landscape.canonical.com/)

---

**Wine allows Ubuntu and linux users to run microsoft programs.**

To install MS adobe reader XI using wine and winetricks, follow these instructions.

Open a terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine winetricks wine1.6* wine-gecko2.21* wine-mono0.0.8 ubuntu-restricted-extras ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

You might not need all of those but installing all of those will give you what you need.

After installing wine, run this command:

```
winetricks -q mspatcha
```

Then, download Adobe Reader XI from [here](http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/11.x/11.0.03/en_US/AdbeRdr11003_en_US.exe) extract the .exe and right-click on the "setup.exe" file in the extracted folder. Choose to open the file using "wine windows program loader". Follow the instructions and agree to accept the user agreement to install Adobe Reader.

Next, download the FileOpen plugin installer from [here](http://plugin.fileopen.com/current/FileOpenInstaller.exe). All you have to do is right click on the installer and choose to open the file using "wine windows program loader". Follow the prompts to install.

One last note. Adobe reader opens without protection mode or something like that so take note if you feel there is some sort of a security risk running certain pdf files.

Also, There's a 30 day free trial available for Adobe Acrobat but you must install AIR first as it is required. [AIR is available here](http://get.adobe.com/air/download/?installer=Adobe_AIR_13.0_for_Win32&standalone=1) (click "download for another computer" and select windows operating system) download the .exe and run it with wine to install. Adobe Acrobat is [available here](https://www.acrobat.com/en_us/free-trial-download.html)(you will have to login or register to download). Open a terminal to first install some dependencies with the following two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install winbind
winetricks atmlib
```

Again, download the .exe, open it with wine, and follow the prompts to install. If you encounter problems, open a terminal and install the file by typing `wine` followed by <kbd>space</kbd> followed by the path to the .exe file (it is usually possible to drag and drop the file into the terminal to automatically fill in the path for you). Any errors will appear in the terminal during the installation along with suggestions and information on how to fix the issue.

More info: [winehq.org](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27093)

and

[fileopen.com](http://plugin.fileopen.com/all.aspx)

Comment: Good idea for calling software-center from an terminal

For PDF viewer, we absolute need FileOpen plugins.
xpdf and poppler are not able to open some secure PDF file

For "Landscape Service", I will check it later

Comment: @SecaThor I've included instructions on how to install the microsoft version of adobe reader and FileOpen using Wine.

Comment: thanks for the HOWTO, I'm on Xubuntu and it's seem that package wine-compholio is not available. I have try anyway to install it and don't seem to work, Adobe Reader open, but FileOpen give error

Comment: @SecaThor I looked into it and you do not need wine-compholio. What kind of error? Does it install fine or are you getting the error when you try to use the plugin?

Comment: I can open regular PDF file  
But when trying to open PDF file that need FileOpen, I got message box "FileOpen client encounter an error. Please restart Adobe Acrobat/Reader"

Comment: @SecaThor I found this command that is suggested for when you install adobe reader; maybe it will help: `winetricks -q mspatcha` source: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27093

Comment: I have try with the, still have the error. We will probably use FileOpen from a RemoteApp, it will be more compatible since Adobe will run in an Windows - Thank you for your help